# what is the intention and real purpose of writer in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

what is the intention of writer in this context? 
"does it say that assertions of that woman and mental position of those who heard them can destroy a serious and crucial investigation?"

> It is a curious psychological study, and equally curious is the mental
>   attitude of the people who could imagine that the assertions of an
>   unbalanced woman, acting not only from motives of hatred but also
>   from—as she herself stated—the hope of pecuniary reward, could upset
>   the critical investigation of a generation of observers.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Comment: The writer is considering the mental attitude of the people who are capable of believing that "the assertions of an unbalanced woman, [...] could upset the critical investigation of a generation of observers."

Comment: @Michael Harvey can you rewrite it in a more simple way?

Comment: It is a curious psychological study. It is also curious that people could imagine that the assertions of Mrs Fox-Kane could upset the critical investigation of a generation of observers. She was an unbalanced woman, who was acting not only from motives of hatred but the hope of pecuniary reward, as she herself stated.

Comment: @Michael Harvey your comment has worth to be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The writer is considering the mental attitude of the people who are capable of believing that "the assertions of an unbalanced woman, [...] could upset the critical investigation of a generation of observers." It could, perhaps, be rewritten thus:

> It is a curious psychological study. It is also curious that people
>   could imagine that the assertions of Mrs Fox-Kane could upset the
>   critical investigation of a generation of observers. She was an
>   unbalanced woman, who was acting not only from motives of hatred but
>   the hope of pecuniary reward, as she herself stated.